# Laguerre polynomials in python using scipy, lack of convergence?

Tags: python, scipy, arbitrary-precision

The laguerre polynomials don't seem to be converging at some orders as can be demonstrated by running the following code.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import mpmath as mp
from scipy.special import genlaguerre as genlag
from sympy.mpmath import laguerre as genlag2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def laguerre(x, r_ord, phi_ord, useArbitraryPrecision=False):
    if (r_ord < 30 and phi_ord < 30) and not useArbitraryPrecision:
        polyCoef = genlag(r_ord, phi_ord)
        out = np.polyval(polyCoef, x)
    else:
        fun = lambda arg: genlag2(r_ord, phi_ord, arg)
        fun2 = np.frompyfunc(genlag2, 3, 1)
        # fun2 = np.vectorize(fun)
        out = fun2(r_ord, phi_ord, x)
    return out

r_ord = 29
phi_ord = 29
f = lambda x, useArb : mp.log10(laguerre(x, 29, 29, useArb))
mp.plot(lambda y : f(y, True) - f(y, False), [0, 200], points = 1e3)
plt.show()
```

I was wondering if anyone knew what is going on or of any accuracy limitations of the `scipy` function? Do you recommend I simply use the `mpmath` function? At first I thought it might be that after a certain order it doesn't work but for (100, 100) it seems to be working just fine.

by running

```
mp.plot([lambda y : f(y, True), lambda y: f(y, False)], [0, 200], points = 1e3)
```

you get the following image where the discrepancy becomes pretty clear.

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: I think you're going to have to explain more about the "strange behavior".  What are you seeing that is not in line with what you expect to be seeing?

Comment: I edited the title, and added a plot, let me know if you still think this doesn't clarify things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `polyval` with high-order polynomials (about `n > 20`) is in general a bad idea, because evaluating polynomial using the coefficients (in power basis) will start giving large errors in floating point at high orders. The [warning](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html#orthogonal-polynomials) in the Scipy documentation tries to  tell you that.

You should use `scipy.special.eval_genlaguerre(r_ord, phi_ord, float(x))` instead of `genlaguerre + polyval`; it uses a stabler numerical algorithm for evaluating the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scipy.special.eval_genlaguerre` to evaluate a high-degree polynomial as pv suggested, you can also use `numpy.polynomial.Laguerre` as explained in the [NumPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html).

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to provide a function for *generalized* Laguerre polynomials.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Laguerre
p = Laguerre([1, -2, 1])
x = np.arange(5)
p(x)
```

NumPy output: 0, 0.5, 2, 4.5, 8