# Python equivalent of Mathematica's "LaguerreL"

Tags: python-2.7, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to plot a function which has a term with a generalized Laguerre polynomial in it. I know Mathematica can use LaguerreL[n, a, f(x,y)], but I'm not sure what the python equivalent would be. I'm currently trying scipy.special.genlaguerre(n, a, (f(x,y)), using x and y as numpy.arange arrays for the values across which I want to plot. but I keep getting the following error:

The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

so I have 2 questions: 1) am I correct in using special.genlaguerre? (I think so)

2) how do I fix the truth value error that numpy is generating here?

Comment: Maybe try the [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) package?

Answer (score 0):

Laguerre polynomials only depend on one variable. You want to evaluate it on x,y positions. In your problem, the one variable you need might be the radius from the origin r.

`scipy.special.genlaguerre` indeeds generate generalized laguerre polynomials. It returns a np.poly1d function. To evaluate this on a range of numbers:

```
rs = np.linspace(0,10)
scipy.special.genlaguerre(1, 0)(rs)
```

In your question, you try to supply f(x,y) as `monic` parameter to `genlaguerre`

If you need the evaluate this polynomial at very high accuracy, read this:
[Laguerre polynomials in python using scipy, lack of convergence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478362/laguerre-polynomials-in-python-using-scipy-lack-of-convergence)